# OCaml - Find the smallest missing number in a sorted list

Tags: arrays, sorting, ocaml

I've been trying to implement a function in OCaml that returns the smallest missing number (greater than 0) in a sorted list.

Here is what I've done

```
let getMissingNumber l = 
        let rec find min = function
        | [] -> min
        | t :: [] -> t + 1
        | t1 :: t2 :: r -> if t2 - t1 > 1 then t1 + 1 else find min (t2 :: r)
    in find 1 l;;
```

Here are the results:

```
# getMissingNumber [1; 4; 5];;
- : int = 2
# getMissingNumber [1; 2; 5];;
- : int = 3
# getMissingNumber [1; 2; 3];;
- : int = 4
# getMissingNumber [3; 4; 5];;
- : int = 6
```

All the results are correct but the last one. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you have a singleton `t::[]` (or `[t]`), you don't compare check whether the value is greater than `min`.

Comment: check if all elements are in sequence, if this is the case (as your last example), return the first element minus 1... but is it possible to implement it along your function - I do not know ;)

Comment: Is the last result really wrong? 6 is the smallest positive integer which is both greater than the smallest element of the input list (aka 3) and not part of the list.

Comment: as @octachron pointed out, the last two results are similar. Maybe it might make more sense to return `0` or `None` since there isn't really any number missing in the sorted sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if list contains more than one element, this function will never return 1, just because of `| t :: [] -> t + 1` (if `t > 0`).

So we may replace `| t :: [] -> t + 1` by `| t :: [] -> min`, but in this case there will be a problem with all lists of the form `[1; 2; 3; ...; n]`, because in the `| t1 :: t2 :: r` branch we don't change `min`, so we will end up by returning 1 (even if correct response is `n+1`).

So we need to "update" `min`, but what's interesting is that if we replace `find min (t2 :: r)` by `find (t2 + 1) (t2 :: r)`, we will return to your original function.

In fact this function search smallest missing number greater than smallest presented number. The main problem is that you distinguish `[t]` and `t1::t2::r` for no good reason.

```
let getMissingNumber l =
  let rec find min = function
    | [] -> min
    | t::r ->
       if t > min then min
       else find (t + 1) r
  in find 1 l
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input list may start with values smaller than one, then you also need to skip over these.

```
let getMissingNumber l = 
        let rec find min = function
        | [] -> min
        | h :: t when min < t -> min
        | h :: t when min = t -> find (min+1) t
        | _ :: t -> find min t
    in find 1 l
```